# Room persistence with retrofit nested object response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

I am trying to store some retrofit response in room db. Retrofit response has nested object, so I'm trying to put it in separate table inside room db, but I'm encountering some problem with foreign keys.

My "Exif" entity from response hasn't an id to use as foreign key in Photo entity, so I put this attribute manually.

When I try to insert photos in room db, it crashes with this error:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (Sqlite code 787), (OS error - 0:Success)

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "photo_table", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Exif::class,
        parentColumns = ["id"],
        childColumns = ["exif"]
    )]
)
class Photo {
    constructor()

    constructor(value: String) {
        val gson = Gson()
        gson.fromJson(value, Photo::class.java)
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: String = ""

   // other stuffs

    @SerializedName("exif")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name="exif")
    var exif: Exif? = null
}


@Entity(tableName = "exif_table")
class Exif {
    constructor()
    constructor(value: String){
        val gson = Gson()
        gson.fromJson(value, Exif::class.java)
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name="id")
    var id: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("model")
    @Expose
    var model: String? = ""
    // Some code
}

class PhotoRepository (private val photoDao: PhotoDao, private val exifDao: ExifDao) {
@WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(photos: List<Photo>){
        val resultIds = ArrayList<Long>()
        photos.forEach { photo ->
            if (photo.exif!=null){
                val exifId = exifDao.addExif(photo.exif!!)
                resultIds.add(photoDao.addPhoto(photo))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have a single class for retrofit complex response and for room db.

Is there a way to use exif attribute in Photo class to "point" to a record in Exif table ?

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of `@Embedded` annotation of `Room` like shown below. In this way, you won't need second table or any foreign key. Also, remove `@ColumnInfo` annotation from `exif` property.

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "photo_table", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Exif::class,
        parentColumns = ["id"],
        childColumns = ["exif"]
    )]
)
class Photo {

    // other stuff

    @SerializedName("exif")
    @Expose
    @Embedded
    var exif: Exif? = null
}
```

If you have object of some other model class where that also contains same variable name than just annotate that object with `@Embedded(prefix = “some_name”)`. This will add your prefix to all the variable name for that class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In json response  I also have other objects like User data, so in the Photo model I have a User attribute. I've shown Exif for semplicity, but I really need to try foreign keys because I will need it for other objects ("user" linked in Photo object will be stored in User table)